# Reference the current CUID in Web-intelligence report in SAP BusinessObjects

Tags: business-objects

When in the 'Modify' mode of a Web-intelligence report inside BusinessObjects, when using the Formula Editor with an object is it possible to identify the CUID from this in a Web Intelligence Report?

I wish to display the CUID on each report, and was hoping there is some variable I can just refer to and it displays accordingly to whatever report I have open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way for this to occur.

The reason is you are looking at 2 different items of data from the way Business Objects is internally structured.  The CUID is part of the metadata stored in the repository database, while the data in the Web Intelligence Report (WebI docs) is store in the actual file that resides on the IFRS.  When working with WebI docs via the SDK, they are 2 very different objects that are manipulated that relate to these different parts.

It might be possible to work around this using the SDK, but I have not tried it.

Recently found a guide to create universe on top of the BusinessObjects CMS database.  [Web Intelligence XI 3.x - Reporting off the BusinessObjects Enterprise CMS Via Data Access DDK](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/weblogs?blog=/pub/wlg/13214)  Once you have the universe for the CMS database, you will then need to bring in *all* document names and the CUID.  Then in the WebI report, you then filter the list of CUIDs using the DocumentName() function.

Comment: Thanks for the time put into your response. This is an annoying missing feature as for our situation we will have to change it manually between the 3 environments (dev/tst/prd). 

Do you know of an equivalent to this, we are using the hardcoded CUID for the link to the report from the chart?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of a work around.  I haven't worked with direct linking between reports.  I usually work with the raw report results and then displaying it in a custom wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a note on CUID... May it help many

http://arkaandbi.blogspot.com/2013/07/a-note-on-cuid.html

Comment: You can reference an outside source.. but you should post the actual answer as well.